# getting a mongoose error while connecting this to controller

Tags: node.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    name: {
        type: String,
        required: [true,'Please Enter Product Name'],
        trim:true,
        maxLength: [100, 'Product Name Cannot Exeed 100 Characters']
    },
    price: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true,'Please Enter Product Price'],
        maxLength: [5, 'Product Price Cannot Exeed 5 Characters']
    },
    description: {
        type: String,
        required: [true,'Please Enter Product Description'],
    },
    ratings: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    images: [
        {
            public_id: {
                type:String,
                required: true
            },
            url:{
                typr:String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ],
    category: {
        typr: String,
        required: [true, 'Please select category for this Product'],
        enum: {
            values: [
                'Electronics',
                'Camera',
                'Laptop',
                'Accessories',
                'HeadPhones',
                'Food',
                'Books',
                'Clothes/Shoes',
                'Beauty/Health',
                'Sports',
                'Outdoor',
                'Home'
            ],
            required: [true, 'Please Select correct category for product']
        }
    },
    seller: {
        type: String,
        required: [true, 'Please enter product seller']
    },
    stock: {
        type: Number,
        required: [true, 'Please enter Product stock number'],
        maxlength:[5, 'Product name connot exceed 5 characters'],
        default: 0
    },
    numOfReviews: {
        type: Number,
        default: 0
    },
    reviews:[
        {
            name: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            },
            rating: {
                type: Number,
                required: true
            },
            comment: {
                type: String,
                required: true
            }
        }
    ],
    createdAt: {
        type: Date,
        default: Date.now
    }

})

module.exports = mongoose.model('Product',productSchema);
```

Comment: throw new TypeError(`Invalid schema configuration: \`${name}\` is not ` +
    ^

TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: `True` is not a valid type at path `url.required`

Comment: can you check `type` spelling in your code. You used `typr` instead of `type`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

can you check `type` spelling in your code. You used `typr` instead of `type`

So, it is throwing `TypeError: Invalid schema configuration: True is not a valid type at path url.required`.

One of those line are:

```
url:{
  typr:String,
  required: true
}
```

You have to use the line as:

```
url:{
  type:String,
  required: true
}
```

Make sure spelling mistakes.